# vue-cli 3.0 multi page setup with HTML5 history mode

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

vue-cli 3.0 provides a pages config to configure multi page mode.

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages

I'm currently trying to get the dev server working with HTML5 history mode, but with no luck so far.

Has anyone already tried this feature and got a working example?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add configuration of devserver to vue.config.js.
By specifying rewrite for historyApiFallback, that problem is solved.

e.g. Implement multiple pages as index page and signin page

vue.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: 'src/entry-point/index/main.js', //entry for the public page
      template: 'public/index.html', // source template
      filename: 'index.html' // output as dist/*
    },
    signin: {
      entry: 'src/entry-point/signin/main.js',
      template: 'public/signin.html',
      filename: 'signin.html'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [
        { from: /\/index/, to: '/index.html' },
        { from: /\/signin/, to: '/signin.html' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**In order to apply the above setting you need to run `vue inspect`, please be careful.**

Also, be careful when **baseUrl is specified**.
The following is stated in the [document](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver).

> Some values like publicPath and historyApiFallback should not be modified as they need to be synchronized with baseUrl for the dev server to function properly.

So, in such a case, set a base tag to the template.

`<base href="/appname/">`

Since this is the configuration of the environment for development, please specify the redirect in the setting of hosting in the production environment.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of how you would set this up for production? I've tried using the rewrites option of the 'connect-hostory-api-fallback' package but the assets (js and css) are not found when the page is redirected