# Having Vue Components as entry point instead of main.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm working with a Java backend and Jersey and want to have the possibility to have different small page app. 
My idea was to have a frontend module in which I would have a folder /apps. 
The folder apps would then contain multiple vue components (that will be the main apps). 
Another folder /component contains the different components that will be used in the different apps. 
The idea is to have a webpack that would create one js file per vue app !

I know that Webpack is not specially designed to have multiple entrypoint / multiple outputs but does anyone have any idea how I could have multiple entry points being the different apps-file.vue and having multiple .js files as output ?

Comment: You should probably remove `java` and `jersey`, because they are part of your server but your question is about client, so they are not really related to this question.

Comment: See the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903246/how-to-create-multiple-output-paths-in-webpack-config You'd still to have a main js file for each app as the entry points to load the Vue components.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52536457/101869) pointed me in the right direction: I followed the Vue CLI docs to add a [`pages` configuration option](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages) in a `vue.config.js` file.

After some experimentation, I got to a solution I was happy with. I saved it in repo that describes step-by-step how to create a multi-page Vue app from scratch.

https://github.com/chriscalo/vue-multipage

Some of the main things I was looking for:

1. Uses the [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/), which means you can avoid **most** webpack
   configuration headaches.
2. Doesn't force you to create an entry point `.js` file for each app /
   page.

With this approach, you just place a bunch of `.vue` files in the `src/pages` directory and it generates a separate Vue app for each one. (You can pretty easily change that folder name from `pages` to `apps` if you would like.)

#### Autogenerate pages config and entry points

The crux of the solution is a script that creates a `src/entry/bar/index.js` entry point file for every `src/pages/bar.vue` file found and also generates a `src/entry/pages.config.js` file that you can import into your `vue.config.js` file like so:

```js
const pagesConfig = require("./src/entry/pages.config.js");

module.exports = {
  pages: pagesConfig,
};
```

Here's the script:

```js
const path = require("path");
const glob = require("fast-glob");
const fse = require("fs-extra");
const R = require("ramda");
const { stripIndent } = require("common-tags");

const pathGlob = processRelativePath("../src/pages/**/*.vue");
const vuePagesPromise = glob(pathGlob);

console.log(`Generating entry points`);

// Step 1: compute specifications for work to be done
const pagesConfigPromise = vuePagesPromise.then(pages => {
  return pages.map(page => {
    const { dir, name } = path.parse(page);
    const entryRoot = path.relative("src/pages", dir);
    const entryName = (
      split(entryRoot, path.sep)
    ).concat(
      ensureEndsWith([name], "index")
    ).join(path.sep);
    const entryFilePath = path.join(
      processRelativePath("../src/entry"), `${entryName}.js`
    );
    const importPath = path.relative("src", page);
    const entryFileContent = entryPointContent(importPath);

    return {
      source: page,
      entryName,
      entryFilePath,
      entryFileContent,
    };
  });
});

// Step 2: clear entry folder
const entryFolderPath = processRelativePath("../src/entry");
fse.removeSync(entryFolderPath);
console.log(`Cleared ${entryFolderPath}`);

// Step 3: create a corresponding entry point file for each page
pagesConfigPromise.then(config => {
  config.forEach(page => {
    fse.outputFileSync(page.entryFilePath, page.entryFileContent);
    console.log(`Created ${page.entryFilePath}`);
  });
});

// Step 4: create a pages.config.js
// module.exports = {
//   "index": 'src/pages/index.js',
//   "login/index": "src/pages/login.js",
//   "profile/index": "src/pages/profile/index.js",
//   "foo/index": 'src/pages/foo.js',
//   "bar/index": 'src/pages/bar/index.js',
// };
const pagesConfigPath = processRelativePath("../src/entry/pages.config.js");
pagesConfigPromise
  .then(config => {
    // transforms each into something like:
    // { "login/index": "src/pages/login.js" }
    return config.map(page => ({
      [page.entryName]: page.entryFilePath,
    }));
  })
  .then(R.mergeAll)
  .then(pageConfigContent)
  .then(content => fse.outputFileSync(pagesConfigPath, content))
  .then(() => console.log(`Created ${pagesConfigPath}`));


function pageConfigContent(config) {
  return stripIndent`
    module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(config, null, 2)};
  `;
}

function processRelativePath(p) {
  const pathToThisDir = path.relative(process.cwd(), __dirname);
  return path.join(pathToThisDir, p);
}

// fixes split() behavior for empty string ("")
function split(string, separator) {
  if (string.length === 0) {
    return [];
  } else {
    return string.split(separator);
  }
}

function ensureEndsWith(array, item) {
  if (array.slice(-1)[0] === item) {
    return array;
  } else {
    return array.concat([item]);
  }
}

function entryPointContent(importPath) {
  return stripIndent`
    import Vue from "vue";
    import page from "@/${importPath}";

    new Vue({
      render: h => h(page),
    }).$mount('#app');
  `;
}
```

Comment: Wow, great script. But is there no simpler solution to this? i.e. A webpack plugin I can install that allows wraps the .vue entry module in an vue render?

Comment: I feel your pain. I really wish Vue would solve this problem, but it doesn't seem like they see file-based routing as something the core Vue library should solve. Nuxt.js is alternative that has file-based routing, you might give that a look.