# How to manage VUE routing builiding a MPA webpage?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, multi-page-application

I'm new using Vue.js. I'm trying to build the frond-end design for a large system for a company. In this system the users have an account where they can access multiple pages to administrate their accounts, interactuate with other accounts, make appoinments, administrate or delete other users, etc. I think that since is a big system, I should use a MPA aproach, because I've read that SPA should not be used for webpages as blogs or online shops because those webpages that are constantly getting updated (as this system will be). 
My question is: I can't find a propper guide to configure MPA on vue, is there one guide for this?

I already followed up this stackoverflow anwser by PJ.Wanderson: [multiple pages in Vue.js CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692018/multiple-pages-in-vue-js-cli) 
but is still have doubts.

Should I still be using the vue router? What kind of configuration should I use there?

How can I handle routes with parameters in this case? Should I use SSR too in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by "because those webpages that are constantly getting updated" what is wrong with constantly updating an spa?

Comment: I'm sorry, I though I read that on an article, but what I actually read was: "If you know you need multiple categories (because, for instance, you run an online shop or publish a lot of other content) — use a multi-page site." but i guess this doesn't has to do with the fact of constatly uploading new information to the system constantly. Anyway, I still think that MPA is the best aproach because there's to much information to display to load it as a single page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build a MPA in Vuejs, your best bet is building it in Nuxt. Nuxt wil handle all the SSR for you. I'm wondering why even build it in Vue in the first place? The reason there isn't that much information on MPA's with Vuejs is because most people build SPA's with it. Another alternative would be to build a SPA in Vuejs and deploy that on a subdomain. Then have al your marketing and other relevant pages on a simple wordpress site. Hope this helped.

Comment: Actually the reason it's because they ask me to develop with Vue. I'm new on that so I thought there would be a simple way of developing a MPA. Do you have any sugestion other than Vue? I would really appreciate your advice.

Comment: Like I said, the simplest way is using Nuxt if they asked you to develop in Vue haha. This is from their site: Build your next Vue.js application with confidence using NuxtJS. With SSR, also called "universal" or "isomorphic" mode, a Node.js server will be used to deliver HTML based on your Vue components to the client instead of the pure javascript. Using SSR will lead to a large SEO boost, better UX and more opportunities (compared to a traditional Vue SPA).