# Vue - how can I customize the route to a page defined in vue.config.js?

Tags: vue.js

Given a vue.config.js file with this setup

```js
pages: {
    index: {
        entry: 'src/main.js',
        template: 'public/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html'
    },
    otherpage: {
        entry: 'src/other.js',
        template: 'public/otherpage.html',
        filename: 'otherpage.html'
    }
}
```

I know I can navigate to the otherpage.html template with this url: `domain/otherpage.html`, but how can I access it with a url like `domain/other`?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857442/vue-cli-3-0-multi-page-setup-with-html5-history-mode

Comment: There's a good starting point. But I think when you're on a production server you'll need to use URL rewrites on that server instead.

Comment: This works indeed with the devserver, thanks! But Im stuck with htaccess rewrite for production.. I'm currently using the standard config from the doc (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations). How can I add a rule to otherpage.html?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure, that's why I posted a comment rather than an answer. Have you searched SO for achieving the same thing on a non-dev server?